# Clear Text selection in document viewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on C# project where I am displaying XPS document in a `DocumentViewer`.
At some point in the code I need to clear text selection that has been made using the mouse (the user will select some text)  does anyone have ideas how to do that (by code)?

Comment: You should provide the steps you have taken so far to solve the problem. Your question is to generic as it is now. (Edit: how did this question pop up, it looks pretty old^^)

Comment: @grek40 it sure is. you've probably received a necromancer badge for it